# In DrRacket how do I check if a string has a certain amount of characters, as well how do I determine what the first character in a string is

Tags: string, list, char, racket

Basically I have a problem, here is the information needed to solve the problem.

4. PigLatin. Pig Latin is a way of rearranging letters in English words for fun. For example, the sentence “pig latin is stupid” becomes “igpay atinlay isway upidstay”.

Vowels(‘a’,‘e’,‘i’,‘o’,and‘u’)are treated separately from the consonants(any letter that isn’t a vowel). 
For simplicity, we will consider ‘y’ to always be a consonant. Although various forms of Pig Latin exist, we will use the following rules:

(1) Words of two letters or less simply have “way” added on the end. So “a” becomes “away”.

(2) In any word that starts with consonants, the consonants are moved to the end, and “ay” is added. If a word begins with more than two consonants, move only the ﬁrst two letters. So “hello” becomes “ellohay”, and “string” becomes “ringstay”.

(3) Any word which begins with a vowel simply has “way” added on the end. So “explain” becomes “explainway”.

Write a function (pig-latin L) that consumes a non-empty (listof Str) and returns a Str containing the words in L converted to Pig Latin. 
Each value in L should contain only lower case letters and have a length of at least 1.

I understand that i need to set three main conditions here, i'm struggling with Racket and learning the proper syntax to write out my solutions. first I need to make a conditions that looks at a string and see if it's length is 2 or less to meet the (1) condition. For (2) I need to look at the first two characters in a string, i'm assuming I have to convert the string into a list of char(string->list). For (3) I understand I just have to look at the first character in the string, i basically have to repeat what I did with (2) but just look at the first character.

I don't know how to manipulate a list of char though. I also don't know how to make sure string-length meets a criteria. Any assistance would be appreciated. I basically have barely any code for my problem since I am baffled on what to do here.

An example of the problem is

```
 (pig-latin (list "this" "is" "a" "crazy" "exercise")) => 
"isthay isway away azycray exerciseway"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best strategy to solve this problem is:

1. Check in the [documentation](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/strings.html) all the available string procedures. We don't need to transform the input string to a list of chars to operate upon it, and you'll find that there are existing procedures that meet all of our needs.
2. Write helper procedures. In fact, we only need a procedure that tells us if a string contains a vowel at a given position; the problem states that only a-z characters are used so we can negate this procedure to also find consonants.

It's also important to identify the best order to write the conditions, for example: conditions 1 and 3 can be combined in a single case. This is my proposal:

```
(define (vowel-at-index? text index)
  (member (string-ref text index)
          '(#\a #\e #\i #\o #\u)))

(define (pigify text)
        ; cases 1 and 3
  (cond ((or (<= (string-length text) 2)
             (vowel-at-index? text 0))
         (string-append text "way"))
        ; case 2.1
        ((and (not (vowel-at-index? text 0))
              (vowel-at-index? text 1))
         (string-append (substring text 1)
                        (substring text 0 1)
                        "ay"))
        ; case 2.2
        (else
         (string-append (substring text 2)
                        (substring text 0 2)
                        "ay"))))

(define (pig-latin lst)
  (string-join (map pigify lst)))
```

For the final step, we only need to apply the `pigify` procedure to each element in the input, and that's what `map` does. It works as expected:

```
(pig-latin '("this" "is" "a" "crazy" "exercise"))
=> "isthay isway away azycray exerciseway"
```

Comment: How do i convert a list of string to just one string at the end of the function, i've been utilizing foldr, string-append and string-join but have been unsuccessful. I don't know how to make spaces between each string when I combine the list of string

Comment: For the end of the function
(define (pig latin L)
I need it so it  combines the the strings into one string, for instance the the example
(pig-latin (list "this" "is" "very" "interesting")) yields

"this is very interesting". I have tried using, string-append, string-join, and foldr with map and it has not worked.
I wrote
(define (pig-latin L)
(foldr string-append " " (map pig L)))

and with (pig-latin(list "this" "is" "very" "interesting") it yielded

"isthayiswayeryvayinterestingway" when it should yield

"isthay isway eryvay interestingway".

There should be spaces

Comment: You just have to call `string-join` in the result, how can that "not work"? see my updated answer.

Comment: For some reason it just says string-join: this function is not defined. I have DrRcket on intermediate student, not sure if that is the reason, I don't think it should be though. I'm not sure why it isn't working, this may just be a problem on my end though unfortunately.

Comment: Aha! that's precisely the reason. You need to use `#lang racket` for it to work, or implement your own `string-join` as I showed in my answer to your previous question.

Comment: found a solution, I have to create a join function which I already did for a previous question I worked on but just forgot about. So the code is working now.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I meant. I was the one that answered that question and provided the `join` implementation :P . I'm glad that it's working now.